# Is there a proper step by step guide to installing and using PhoneGap?

Tags: eclipse, cordova

Is it just me or the documentation for PhoneGap installation is ridiculous? The steps are all over the place and no clear path to installing and using it. I found a couple of decent guides for use on MAC but nothing that is clear for Windows.

Got frustrated and uninstalled everything, eclipse, cordova, ant, android.

I want to just restart fresh with a clean install. Can anyone show me to a guide which has a step by step guide to windows. Or maybe you could guide me to exactly which are the stuff I need to install for phoneGap to work? For example is ant(apache) even needed? Not every guide mentions it.

I believe over all, the steps includes 2 parts. 1 is installing the various components such as eclipse and so on. 2nd is to interlink all these various components.

Not exaggerating but I've been at this for a week plus now and have looked around for a clear instruction and found nothing. Please help.

PS: If PhoneGap can be installed and linked with NetBeans, it would be great to know exactly how. Tnks.

Comment: The documentation of the CLI is quite clear in my opinion. There may be confusion because of cordova/phonegap, but that appart, it seems quite clear. Have you followed instructions in this page? http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: also about android specific part, http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide                      And about the PS, starting with netbeans 7.4 you can create a new cordova project by just doing New project->HTML5->Cordova application.

Comment: I am using 7.4 netbeans now. You mean I can just open a phoneGap project w/o any other downloads such as android? Cos new project only points to Java, JavaFX, Maven, Netbean modules and Samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only java, javafx in netbeans because you installed netbeans java edition.

Cordova is in the HTML5 package which is included in other editions like java EE edition or php edition.

In your netbeans version, you have to install the plugin:
Tools->Plugins-Available plugins, check HTML5 and click install.

Then you should be able to use the New project->HTML5->Cordova application.

You will still need cordova, android, ant... but the difference is that netbeans should setup everything for you.

Sorry I can't confirm as I have installed everything before netbeans.

Comment: I'm able to get the HTML5->Cordova Application. Clicking next tells me  my cordova is not installed. But it is already installed. I tried running cordova -version on command prompt and it also returns me the version it is on.